# Faster Way to Translate DataFrame Column to Feature and Target Matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column (binary) in a dataframe (df) of the form:

```
Vector
0
1
0
1
0
.
.
.
```

I am using this in a binary classification model. My objective is to take these 0's and 1's and move them into two seperate lists, which then get translated into numpy arrays. As an example, I would like to move the first 5 items from Vector into X, then the 6th item into Y. Then the next 5 items into X, and then the following 6th item into Y, till the end of the df (currently 200k rows).

My first instinct is to write a for loop for this (but I know this is hugely inefficient):

```py
for i in range(0, df.shape[0] - 6):
        # as we iterate through the df
        # we will use a step of 5
        if i_cnt > 5:
            y = df['Vector'].iloc[i]
            Y.append(y)
            i_cnt = 1
        else:
            x = df['Vector'].iloc[i]
            X.append(x)
            i_cnt +=1
```

There is definitely a faster way to do this and hoping someone knows how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modulo with `6` by array created by length of index and compare for `X` and `Y`:

```
#sample data for easy verify

df = pd.DataFrame({'Vector': range(20)})

idx = np.arange(len(df)) % 6
```

---

```
X = df.loc[idx < 5, 'Vector']
print (X)

0        0
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
6        6
7        7
8        8
9        9
10      10
12      12
13      13
14      14
15      15
16      16
18      18
19      19

Y = df.loc[idx == 5, 'Vector']
print (Y)
 
5        5
11      11
17      17
```

If output format is different - `X` is `2d array` use `reshape` with `-1` for automatic count length with `6` and select by indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Vector': range(18)})


arr = df['Vector'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 6)

X = arr[:, :-1]
Y = arr[:, -1]
print (X)
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]
 [12 13 14 15 16]]

print (Y)
[ 5 11 17]
```

Comment: on line `idx = df.index % 6` I get the following error: `TypeError: cannot perform __mod__ with this index type: Index`

Comment: @Dean - Then need `idx = np.arange(len(df)) % 6`

Answer (score 1):

For `k = 5 + 1 = 6`,

```
k = 6

n_rows = len(df.index)
n_samples = n_rows // k

X_and_y = df.Vector.to_numpy().reshape(n_samples, k)

X = X_and_y[:, :-1]
y = X_and_y[:, -1]
```

We reshape the column to a `(n_samples, 5 + 1)` array where `n_samples = n_rows / 6`, then we take all but last column into `X` and last column into `y`.

e.g.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=18), columns=["Vector"])
>>> df
    Vector
0        0
1        0
2        1
3        1
4        0
5        0
6        0
7        0
8        0
9        0
10       0
11       1
12       0
13       0
14       1
15       0
16       0
17       1

>>> # after

>>> X
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

>>> y
array([0, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
X = list(df[df.index % 6 < 5]["Vector"])
y = list(df[df.index % 6 == 5]["Vector"])
```

Comment: I get the following error: `TypeError: cannot perform __mod__ with this index type: Index`

Comment: Can you share output of `df.index`?

Comment: Try `x = list(df[df.reset_index().index % 6 < 5]["Vector"])` and 
`y = list(df[df.reset_index().index % 6 == 5]["Vector"])`